# como poner corchetes lista Python?

Tags: python

como podría hacer para mostrar el resultado de rotar_vector entre corchetes en el siguiente código? me lo muestra de la siguiente manera:

A = [7, 0, 6, 9, 2, 9]

6
9
10
7
0
9

y yo quiero que me lo muestre asi:

B = [6
9
10
7
0
9]

```
import random

def rotar_vector(lista):
for i in range(6,0,-1):
    print(lista[(6-k)-i])

lista = [0]  * 6
k = int(input("Ingrese un numero: "))

for i in range(6):
lista[i] = random.randint(0, 10)

        

print("A = " + str(lista))

rotar_vector(lista)
```

Comment: Si solo quieres imprimirlo entre corchetes, añádelos al print

Comment: print(lista[-k:] + lista[:-k])

Answer (score 1):

Una manera sencilla de hacerlo sería almacenando el valor de la lista según la vas rotando en otra lista auxiliar que luego imprimes, justo como haces con la primera:

```
import random

def rotar_vector(lista):
    nueva_lista = []
    for i in range(6,0,-1):
        nueva_lista.append(lista[(6-k)-i]) # Añade el número a la lista
    print("B =", nueva_lista) # Al terminar el bucle, imprime la nueva lista

lista = [0]  * 6
k = int(input("Ingrese un numero: "))

for i in range(6):
    lista[i] = random.randint(0, 10)

        

print("A = " + str(lista))

rotar_vector(lista)
```

Otra opción es usar un [list comprehension](https://www.learnpython.org/es/List%20Comprehensions) para evitar las listas intermedias, pero aquí las cosas se pueden poner un poco... *marcianas*:

```
import random

def rotar_vector(lista):
    print("B = [", ", ".join(str(lista[(6-k)-i]) for i in range(6,0,-1)),"]", sep="")


lista = [0]  * 6
k = int(input("Ingrese un numero: "))

for i in range(6):
    lista[i] = random.randint(0, 10)

        

print("A = " + str(lista))

rotar_vector(lista)
```

Resultado:

```
A = [3, 10, 0, 9, 9, 5]
B = [10, 0, 9, 9, 5, 3]
```

Te recomiendo leer la documentación que te dejé en el enlace de arriba y practicar un poco con ello si quieres entenderlo, las list comprehension son muy poderosas, pero pueden ser un poco complicadas de entender

Comment: sin utilizar append hay algún modo?

Comment: He añadido una manera sin utilizar append, pero creo que descubrirás que usando una lista intermedia las cosas eran más fáciles! :) Un saludo y espero que te sirva